# Are educational questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Looking at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, I cannot find a clear answer if educational questions are off-topic, like a teacher asking for an alternative way to explain a certain concept to his/her students.

Comment: Since clarification of chemical concepts are on topic, I'd say that asking for alternative explanations are on topic, too. The question should probably focus on the concept rather than the didactics of teaching it.